# Flush output of child process

Tags: perl, process, output, buffer

I created a child process via `IPC::Open2`.
I need to read from the stdout of this child process line by line.
Problem is, as the stdout of the child process is not connected to a terminal, it's fully buffered and I can't read from it until the process terminates.

**How can I flush the output of the child process without modifying its code ?**

---

*child process code*

```
while (<STDIN>) {
    print "Received : $_";
}
```

*parent process code:*

```
use IPC::Open2;
use Symbol;

my $in = gensym();
my $out = gensym();

my $pid = open2($out, $in, './child_process');

while (<STDIN>) {
    print $in $_;
    my $line = <$out>;
    print "child said : $line";
}
```

---

When I run the code, **it get stucks waiting the output of the child process**.
However, if I run it with `bc` the result is what I expect, I believe `bc` must manually flush its output

note:
In the child process if I add `$| = 1` at the beginning or `STDOUT->flush()` after printing, the parent process can properly read from it.
However this is an example and I must handle programs that don't manually flush their output.

Comment: Some quick looking on metacpan suggests [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) might be worth looking into; it has a way to run a process in a pseudo tty which might avoid the buffering problem you're encountering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to (try to) deal with buffering is to set up a terminal-like environment for the process, a pseudo-terminal (pty). That is not easy to do in general but [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) has that capability ready for easy use.

Here is the driver, run for testing using [at](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html) facility so that it has no controlling terminal (or run it via `cron`)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use IPC::Run qw(run);
    
my @cmd = qw(./t_term.pl input arguments); 
    
run \@cmd, '>pty>', sub { say "out: @_" };

#run \@cmd, '>', sub { say "out: @_" }   # no pty
```

With `>pty>` it sets up a pseudo-terminal for `STDOUT` of the program in `@cmd` (with `>` it's a pipe); also see `<pty<` and see more [about redirection](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run#Redirection-Operators).
The anonymous `sub {}` gets called every time there is output from the child, so one can process it as it goes. There are other related options.

The program that is called (`t_term.pl`) only tests for a terminal

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

say "Is STDOUT filehandle attached to a terminal: ",
    ( (-t STDOUT) ? "yes" : "no" );
sleep 2;
say "bye from $$";
```

The `-t STDOUT` (see [filetest operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)) is a suitable way to check for a terminal in this example.  For more/other ways see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53133604/4653379).

The output shows that the called program (`t_term.pl`) does see a terminal on its `STDOUT`, even when a driver runs without one (using `at`, or out of a `crontab`). If the `>pty>` is changed to the usual redirection `>` (a pipe) then there is no terminal.

Whether this solves the buffering problem is clearly up to that program, and to whether it is enough to fool it with a terminal.

Another way around the problem is using `unbuffer` when possible, as in mob's answer.

Comment: If I want to `cd` to a specific location before doing this `run \@cmd, '>pty>', sub { say "out: @_" }`, how should I modify this command ? The file that I want to run cannot be run from other locations.

Comment: @him  Do you mean `chdir`?  That changes script's working directory.  So if you do `chdir $dir` in the script then if there is a program (say, `prog`) in that directory you can run it without path (so just `./prog` or probably even `prog`).   It's a direct equivalent of doing `cd dir` on the command line and then running `prog`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I have a script to run another program, before running that command I want to change my current directory to some other location from inside the script just for running the program - the program can't be run from elsewhere. I tried to write something like `run \@cdCmd, '>pty>', sub { say "out: @_" }, '|', \@cmd, '>pty>', sub { say "out: @_" }` but it says `'cd' not found ....`. This may be because `cd` is a builitin shell command. So, I wanted to know a method to do this.

Comment: @him OK, so that's what I said -- add `chdir $dir;`to your script, and after that you can do `run \@cmd ...` (`$dir` is directory you need to be in, where that program is).  The Perl builtin to change the working directory of the script is [chdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html), which you run as a separate command first.

Comment: @him  Try this on the command line: `perl -MCwd -wE'$d=shift//".."; say "in: ", cwd; chdir $d; say "now in: ", cwd'`.  The program prints the working directory, then changes it (by default just to one directory up, `..`), then it prints it again. You can give it the directory to go to: `perl -MCwd -wE'...' dir-to-go-to`

Comment: @him Once you do `chdir $dir;` don't forget that after that point your script runs in `$dir`! So if you need to change back to where you started it, record where you are (using `cwd` from `Cwd` module) before the change so that you can change back once you need that

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Perl has no control over the buffering behavior of the programs it executes. Some systems have an [`unbuffer`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man1/expect_unbuffer.1.html) utility that can do this. If you have access to this tool, you could say

```
my $pid = open2($out, $in, 'unbuffer ./child_process');
```

There's a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516258/what-is-the-equivalent-of-unbuffer-program-on-windows) about the equivalent tools for Windows, but I couldn't say whether any of them are effective.