# How to make external command's output autoflush with AnyEvent::Subprocess?

Tags: perl, anyevent

I am trying to monitor the output of an external command with [`AnyEvent::Subprocess`](https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Subprocess):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use AnyEvent::Subprocess;

my $job = AnyEvent::Subprocess->new(
    delegates     => [ 'StandardHandles', 'CompletionCondvar' ],
    code          => 'myscript.pl',
);
my $run = $job->run;
my $condvar = $run->delegate('completion_condvar');

$run->delegate('stdout')->handle->on_read(
    sub {
        my ( $handle ) = @_;
        my $line = $handle->rbuf;
        chomp $line;
        say "Got output: '$line'";
        $handle->rbuf = ""; # clear buffer
      }
);
my $done = $condvar->recv;
```

In general, I do not have access to the source code of the external script, so I cannot insert commands like `STDOUT->autoflush(1)` into the script (if the script happens to be a Perl script).

Here is the test script I used for testing:

**myscript.pl**:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

#STDOUT->autoflush(1);
sleep 1;
say "data 1";
sleep 1;
say "data 2";
sleep 1;
say "data 3";
```

The output is coming all at once after `myscript.pl` finishes. I want to print each line from `myscript.pl` as it becomes available. How can this be done without modifying `myscript.pl` ?

Comment: Would  `unbuffer` or a pseudo-terminal (pty) help, like on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54538273/4653379)

Comment: @zdim Yes this seems to work: `sudo apt-get install expect`, and then using `unbuffer` with `myscript.pl`. Thanks for the link!